# Dominated Convergence on risk measures

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, convex-analysis

This is a quite specific question and I am not able to provide the whole background (e.g. what a risk measure is). If someone knows that would be great. I am having difficulties understanding a certain point within a proof. We have the following:

$\rho(X)=\inf\{ m \in \mathbb{R} | E[l(-m-X)] \leq x_{0} \}$ where

1. $\rho$ is a convex measure of risk,
2. $X \in \mathcal{X}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the class of all bounded
       measurable functions on some given probability space
       $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$
3. $l$ is convex loss function (increasing
      and not identically constant)
4. $x_{0}$ is an interior point of range of $l$.

What I do not understand is why $\rho(X)$ is the solution of $E[l(-z-X)]=x_{0}$ (it is also the unique solution but that I understand).  
For those who recognize this point is part of the the proof of Prop. 4.59 on p.199 (eq. 4.54) from the book of H. Foellmer and A. Schied "Stochastic Finance". The authors state that $\rho(X)$ is a solution because of dominated convergence but I fail to recognize how and why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}$$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$I would agree that the proof in the book is confusing. It seems to me that we do not need the dominated convergence theorem to show the equivalence of the two problems - we only need it to show that $\rho$ is continuous from below.

Let $z^*\in\Re$ be the unique solution of

$$\E[\ell(-z^*-X)-x_0]=0.$$

Is this the (unique) solution/optimal value of $\inf\{z: \E[\ell(-z^*-X)-x_0]\leq 0\}$?

First, note that $z^*$ is a feasible point of the optimization problem. Suppose that $z^*$ is not an optimizer. Then, there will be a $z^{**}$ which is feasible, i.e.,

$$\E[\ell(-z^{**}-X)]\leq 0 = \E[\ell(-z^{*}-X)],$$

but $z^{**} < z^*$. However, this is a contradiction because $\E[\ell(-z-X)]$ is strictly decreasing in $z$ (because $\ell$ is strictly increasing and $\E$ is strongly monotone).

The authors use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $\rho$ is continuous from below.